# Unable to logoout of openID RPXnow

Tags: openid, rpxnow

Hi I am using RPXnow for logging in my website.
I am able to login through yahoo/google/ account.
when I logout of my website I get logged out of my website & session is killed.

However if click back to sign in again through rpx widget I am transferred to yahoo/
google which is already signed in.I do not have to reenter my user name,password.

How can i solve this?Do i have to send some info through /to rpxnow to signout of my yahoo/
google account when i logout at my website.
All I do is session.invalidate(); to logout.I could not find any step to logout in their document.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what you want to do, when the user logs out of your website, they're logging out of your website, not google/yahoo, if they want to logout of their openId provider's website they have to go there.

Comment: In that case, i must redirect my users to openID providers to ensure they are logged out completely. but i dont find any method to redirect to them without a rpx widget.

Comment: When you're using openId, you stay logged into the provider, so you can log into other sites without entering your passwords. (Using Google for openId anyway) if you log out of stackoverflow, and then hit login again, you will not have to enter your openId password